# Child Process VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

My aim is to create a child processes which will execute in parallel the piece of VB.NET code say a function. I want to do it specifically using processes and not threads. Please suggest the ways to do this?

Comment: Why? (This will help get a good answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method. Obviously the piece of code you would like to be executed in a separate process should reside in this process. It cannot reside in the caller process.

Another possibility is to create a new [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s0z09xw.aspx) instead of process.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class with the [`Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92699yzt.aspx) method.

Check the [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfbyhds5.aspx) class to see what you options you can use to start a process.

However, the process will be separate - you will not have control over it and it cannot be a "sub-process". If you need more control, you should reconsider using threads.